# How to increase accessibility for test files for my coding students?

Tags: file, server

I am a C++ teacher and I have a couple of students. I have my student do alot of programs that require I/O but I would hate having them download the files. Is there a way I can put the files online and they just access it from their computers by passing the address of the file on some public online file server to the program?

Comment: GitHub? Google Drive? A website?

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you want to provide program code in an online text editor, and not as a file download.
As this was (erroneously?) tagged "accessibility", I'll answer the question from the screen reader accessibility perspective.
Unfortunately, there are no known fully accessible online code editors these days. All of them use some techniques that prevent screen readers from reading the code when your user navigates it with his/her keyboard and namely arrow keys. This is actually a huge problem of many online courses.
So what I suggest you to do is to make a repository on Github (or on Gitlab, if you want a free and private repo) and teach your students to work with Git from the very beginning, this will be very helpful in their future developers life. Avoid Bitbucket since these days (June 2017) it seems very far from being accessible to screen reader users.